# When using the open command, and O_CREAT, it is appending a "?" to the end of the file name, how do I remove this?

Tags: c, io, stdout, stdin

So I am using the open function in C to open a target file, and if it does not exist, I will create it. I am redirecting stdout from the terminal into this file. When I run my program, it creates a new file with the name that I type into the shell, but appends a "?" to the end. Can someone help me figure out how to remove that?

My code is below

```
// Take output from ls as input into the next argument.
                    command = strtok(NULL, " "); // Holds the value for the destination file.
                    printf("%s\n", command);
                    int targetFD = open(command, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0700);
                    if (targetFD == -1)
                    {
                        perror("open()");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    printf("The file descriptor for targetFD is %d\n", targetFD);
                    int result = dup2(targetFD, 1);
                    if (result == -1)
                    {
                        perror("dup2");
                        exit(2);
                    }
                    ls(); // instead of printing ls to the terminal, it gets written to the file.
```

Here is an image of a sample execution. Notice how junk.txt file already exists...I want my program to redirect "ls" into that file or create a new one of the file does not exist.
[sample program execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJs8T.png)

Comment: Code is too incomplete. For example, what buffer is `strtok` operating on? That is, missing first `strtok` call. Please provide complete code as a [mre]. Note that it means the smallest amount of complete code that anyone can copy exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, please do not post screen shots of text output. Copy the text directly into the question.

Answer (score 3):

I bet the `?` is not a literal `?` character, but the way that your version of `ls` displays a filename containing a non-printable character, e.g. if you use GNU `ls` and have the `-q` option enabled by default.

I also note that in your sample output, there is an extra blank line between `junk.txt` and `The file descriptor for targetFD`.  You only printed one newline after `command`, so I suspect that the string `command` itself ends with a `\n`.  That would fit if it was parsed from a string that ended with `\n` (e.g. a line read with `fgets`).  So you actually created a file named `junk.txt\n`, and `ls` prints the newline character as `?`.

Perhaps you wanted to use `" \n"` as the delimiter string for `strtok`, so that a newline will also be treated as a delimiter and not be included in the token string.

Comment: Wow that did the trick, thank you very much!!!